# Unable to debug Kivy in PyCharm while run is OK

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

**I have an issue on debugging a Kivy project with PyCahrm.**

I'm on Win 10 x64.

Config version ***1***:

- Python: **3.7.9 x64**
- Kivy: **2.0.0**
- PyCharm (Community Edition): **2022.1.1**

Config version ***2***:

- Python: **3.10.4 x64**
- Kivy: **2.1.0**
- PyCharm (Community Edition): **2022.1.1**

First, I need to say that with `Config version 1` I worked bevor and still have no problems.

**What I did:**

- installed Python 3.10
- created new venv
- installed Kivy
- installed other for my project required packages
- added Python Interpreter to the Project in PyCharm
- edited Run/Debug configuration to new interpreter in PyCharm

If I just run the project, it works like I expected without any errors, but if I try to debug it, I always get an Exception.
With MS VSCode I'm able to debug the Project, so I assume there is something with my configuration in PyCharm.

This is my console Output while debugging in PyCharm:

```
[WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (21 instead of 24)
[WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[DEBUG  ] [Config      ] Upgrading from 21 to 22
[DEBUG  ] [Config      ] Upgrading from 22 to 23
[DEBUG  ] [Config      ] Upgrading from 23 to 24
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\x\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-05-30_23.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Projects\My Project\venv310\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Projects\My Project\venv310\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.resourcefind> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] available extensions: b'GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_NV_blend_square GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_barrier GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_NV_conditional_render GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_cl_event GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_timer_query GL_EXT_timer_query GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_INTEL_fragment_shader_ordering GL_ARB_fragment_shader_interlock GL_ARB_clip_control GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_ARB_compute_shader GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_shader_image_size GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index GL_ARB_query_buffer_object GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_ARB_clear_texture GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_ARB_texture_query_levels GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_INTEL_map_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_ARB_copy_image GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_EXT_direct_state_access GL_ARB_stencil_texturing GL_ARB_texture_stencil8 GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location GL_ARB_multi_bind GL_ARB_indirect_parameters '
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glShaderBinary is not available
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3.0 - Build 20.19.15.5126'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30 - Build 20.19.15.5126'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load <C:\Projects\My Project\venv310\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[WARNING] Both Window.minimum_width and Window.minimum_height must be bigger than 0 for the size restriction to take effect.
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: winctypes
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "C:\Projects\My Project\src\My_App.py", line 27, in <module>
     import doctodb.sql_utils as slq_utils  # sqlite3 & Co.
   File "C:\Projects\My Project\src\doctodb\sql_utils.py", line 14, in <module>
     import my_globals
   File "C:\Projects\My Project\src\my_globals.py", line 12, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Projects\My Project\venv310\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 414, in <module>
     from os.path import dirname, join, exists, sep, expanduser, isfile
 ImportError: cannot import name 'sep' from 'ntpath' (C:\Python\Python310\lib\ntpath.py)
 Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from 'C:\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\threading.py'>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1560, in _shutdown
     lock.acquire()
 KeyboardInterrupt: 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea what could I try to solve this?

Comment: Hi, @Roman B.,  Have you solved this issue? I met the same problem and want to know how you fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JilongYin, unfortunately I was unable to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need to dig more..